# Are there literal strings in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-literals

In F# there is something called a `literal string` (not `string literal`), basically if a string literal is preceded by `@` then it is interpreted as-is, without any escapes.

For example if you want to write the path of a file in Windows(for an `os.walk` for example) you would do it like this:

`"d:\\projects\\re\\p1\\v1\\pjName\\log\\"`

Or you could do this(the F# way):

`@"d:\projects\re\p1\v1\pjName\log\"`

The second variant looks much more clear and pleasing to the eye. Is there something of the sort in python? The documentation doesn't seem to have anything regarding that.

I am working in Python 3.6.3.

Comment: Have you tried raw or unicode strings like `path = r'"d:\projects\re\p1\v1\pjName\log\"`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Note that a string literal cannot end with a single backslash, even if you use raw strings. One way to work around that is to use literal string concatenation, eg `path = r'd:\projects\re\p1\v1\pjName\log' '\\'`

Answer (score 4):

There are: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

You can use `r` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

TL;DR use little r

```
myString = r'\n'
```

Comment: Think you meant to do: `\n`.

Comment: To show that it will escape, and not go down a line :)